# Becoming a sharepoint developer

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I would like to become a Sharepoint developer, can any point tell me what path they took to reach their goals?

Comment: possible duplicate of [From .NET developer to SharePoint developer - Can it happen?](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/22435/from-net-developer-to-sharepoint-developer-can-it-happen)

Comment: "can any point tell me what path they took to reach their goals?" - start developing and continue developing ....

Answer (score 1):

While Falak may be right that this is a duplicate I would like to add that now is actually an ideal time to start on this path.  SharePoint 2013 is right around the corner and it brings with it a brand new way to develop for SharePoint - the [App Web model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp179930.aspx).  Developing for SharePoint like this is new to everyone and does not require the STEEP learning curve associated with traditional SharePoint development so you could be productive reasonably fast.

SharePoint Apps are likely going to be a huge growth area as well, especially with Microsoft pushing the cloud so much in 2013.