# .Net to SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-online

I have 1 years of experience in asp.net.
I have worked with MVC, asp.net, C#, JQUERY, CSS.

I want to learn something new so I have chosen SharePoint because of market demand and salary.

I am very much confused that I have to remain in dot net or I have to switch to SharePoint?

The following questions are in my mind, if someone can help me to come out of this confusion, I am very thankful.

1. Future of SharePoint?, is it possible that after few years SharePoint demand will go very down as flex?
2. Is SharePoint difficult to learn?
3. Is SharePoint programming is very difficult from asp.net?
4. I heard that nobody give SharePoint work to a fresher, is it so?
5. I did not get any SharePoint video tutorial can someone provide me the links?

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint is an application that sits on top of ASP.net. They do override a lot of ASP.net built-in functionality (they have their own .aspx Parser and Virtual Path Provider for example).

With ASP.net you have a very well documented, battle-hardened, mature and stable platform with a good API.

With SharePoint you gain a poorly documented, bug-ridden, very limited application that handles a lot of features that you would have to code yourself (e.g., User Profile Management, Document Organization and Versioning and Social Features like Commenting and Tagging), although for the most point SharePoint handles them really poorly and does not allow you to override them, which means that you spend a lot of time rewriting them anyway and trying to integrate them back.

Basically my advice as a SharePoint developer: Use it when you absolutely have to, avoid it whenever you can and stay with just ASP.net.

SharePoint is good as a simple document management and very light social system. You can quickly customize smaller parts of it and add a lot of value to your company. But in the moment you need something that even only slightly different from what Microsoft envisions, you hit a wall that you can't pass. It's great for what it does, nothing more, nothing less.

**As a ASP.net developer, you can get an idea of SharePoint using the following links,**

> 1. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff829215.aspx
> 2. http://sharepoint-tutorial.net/post/2013/01/21/sharepoint-2010-development-overview.aspx
> 3. http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/dhananjaycoder/architecture-of-sharepoint-for-Asp-Net-developers/
> 4. https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/devwiki/SP2010Dev/Pages/The%2012%20factors%20to%20turn%20ASP.NET%20developers%20to%20SharePoint%202010.aspx

For working with Visual Studio to develop SharePoint solutions, refer the below URL's

> 1. msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330921(v=vs.100).aspx
> 2. msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231568.aspx

Comment: Thanks Karthink. Your ans is no or yes to sharepoint for me??

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't think SharePoint is for you right now - but that doesn't mean that it isn't later.

Why? Taking from an answer posted here: [From .NET developer to SharePoint developer - Can it happen?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/22435/from-net-developer-to-sharepoint-developer-can-it-happen?rq=1)

> On the surface, SharePoint might look like a single platform, but at
>   the heart of it you will need to know a lot more than what SharePoint
>   is. Besides learning SharePoint, you will need to learn Business
>   Intelligence, Active Directory, Exchange, WCF, WWF, Windows Identity,
>   and list goes on. My point is that it is just not enough to learn
>   SharePoint, you will need to learn many other technologies that SP
>   interacts with.
>
> A lot of people give up on SharePoint not because there is big
>   learning curve, but simply because the development process is much
>   more involved than ASP.NET (ex: deploying your solution). SharePoint
>   is ASP.NET plus everything else out there (JQuery, SilverLight,
>   Mobile, etc.). Almost anything you can imagine, there is a way to
>   integrate with SharePoint.

By your own words you are only one year into your development experience with ASP.net. I would focus on building upon what you know there, not adding something new (that has a huge learning curve) into the mix. You are going to be substantially more marketable by being a more skilled ASP.net developer then you are as a novice ASP developer that also knows a little bit about SharePoint.

Comment: I learnt WCF by my own.Definately not everything.But i know the concepts of WCF.Till the time i did not get real work or exposure you cannot grow i think so.

Comment: @sahil Not to be too harsh, but this likely means you don't understand a lot of the industry standards or how to develop in a corporate environment. There's a lot more to development beyond languages and I think you should focus on learning more about these things rather than overloading your plate by adding SharePoint to it right now.

Comment: I am not rude.Sorry if you feel like..Actually right now i am very confused so..Can you suggest what should be next move??means which technology i have to focus on?

Comment: I definitely didn't think you were rude - we're getting a bit lost in translation I think. I think you should focus on becoming better at ASP.net by working on some corporate projects and getting a feel for the ebb and flow of large scale development. Once you have more experience there, and are more marketable you may even decide that you don't need SharePoint in your portfolio to get employment. If you still do at that point, that's when I would explore it.